# JNI: how to use GetMethodID for getScanResults

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I want to call java in C though jni, but I have a problem:

My code as follows:

```
m = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "getScanResults", "()[B");
LOG_INFO("startScan Failed %d, %d", __LINE__,m);
jobjectArray rArray  = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, wifiMgrObj, m);
...
```

but 'm' always return 0. 
I think "()[B" maybe wrong, but i don't know howto FIXIT, can anyone help me?

---

Here is the android API about 'getScanResults'
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()

```
getScanResults

Added in API level 1
List<ScanResult> getScanResults ()
Return the results of the latest access point scan.

Returns List<ScanResult>    the list of access points found in the most recent scan. An app must hold ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in order to get valid results. If there is a remote exception (e.g., either a communication problem with the system service or an exception within the framework) an empty list will be returned.
```

Comment: see http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0286.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The API you have cited says it returns a `List<ScanResult>`.
- The JNI signature you have provided to `GetMethodID()` says it returns a `byte[]`. It doesn't.

Moral: don't guess about JNI signatures. Use the result of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: Can you give me a example? I tried ,but not work:
m = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "getScanResults", "()[ScanResult");

Comment: @zs2014 as EJP said: `"Moral: don't guess about JNI signatures"`, did yo try `javap -s`? this will answer your question

Comment: @zs2014 I don't know why you would need  an example of `javap -s`. I can't  convince myself that you've actually read my answer.

Comment: @zs2014 While you're at it, pipe the results of your `javap` call to `grep -A 2 "getScanResults"`.